# Google DataStudio - regex to extract first part of page title, before > character

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

DataStudio shows each page of a report separately, in this format

```
Report 1 > Page 1
Report 1 > Page 2
Report 2 > Page 4
etc
```

I'm trying to show sessions for Reports only, regardless of page. 
I created a calculated field "Report Name", using this regex to get everything up to the > character:

`REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page Title,'^.+?>')`

But it doesn't work. 
This is the Google-RE2 syntax https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the regex.. re2 supports your regex and gives expected results. Check your syntax,quotes etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks very much.

It was a simple issue in the end. The delimiting character is actually › not >

It also needed additional brackets around the expression.

So this works:

`REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page Title,'(^[^›]+)')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this regexp for capturing group 1 :

```
/^([^>]+) >/
```

or :

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page Title,'^[^>]+')
```

Fiddle [here](https://regex101.com/r/RLht4F/1)

If it's not what you want, please provide more details & test-cases

Comment: Thanks for this. Looking at the Fiddle, that does exactly what I'm after. But in DataStudio it's giving null for the Report Name (for all reports).